# Save and get image from folder inside Documents folder on iOS wrong path

Tags: ios, swift, nsdocumentdirectory

On application launch I'm creating a folder inside the Documents directory, if there is none there already. This works great!

I'm downloading some images and would like to save them to use them later. 
My problem is that my code seems to store the files in a documents directory that is not the same that would be on the next app launch.
I know that since iOS8 the documents directory can change from launch to launch. So I'm always retrieving a path to the Documents folder. Could someone answer me why this code can't get the path to the image correctly?

```
func requestImage(let url: String,let isbn: String, numberInRow: Int){
    var documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    documentsPath.appendContentsOf("/bookImages")
    print("Image folder path is: \(documentsPath)")
///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E6B66A15-F166-46FE-A577-9B0D911F5C92/Documents/bookImages

    let pathComponent = isbn.stringByAppendingString(".jpg")
        print("Suggested filename: \(pathComponent)") //1234567891234.jpg

        let imagePath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingString("/\(pathComponent)")
        print("Image to be saved at: \(imagePath)")
// /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E6B66A15-F166-46FE-A577-9B0D911F5C92/Documents/bookImages/9788202350420.jpg
        if (data != nil){
            NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(imagePath, contents: data!, attributes: ["YES" : "NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey"])

            self.books[numberInRow].setValue(pathComponent, forKey: "imageurl")
        }



    }
```

When I would like to display these images I have this in the view controller

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
let imageFolderPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingString("/bookImages")


if let image = bookData.valueForKey("imageurl") as? String
            {
                print("Imagepath: \(self.imageFolderPath)/\(image)")
// /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DB1F6FE9-1071-41A6-9E87-2A3D32ECD2B9/Documents/bookImages/9788202350420.jpg
let imagePath = self.imagePath.stringByAppendingString("/\(image)")

                reuseableCell.bookCover.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
            }
```

I removed a lot of code that was not relevant. Why can't the image be displayed be found?

If anyone understand the error code, it is here:

```
BOMStream BOMStreamWithFileAndSys(int, off_t, size_t, int, char *, BomSys *): read: No such file or directory
```

Edit:
On application launch I'm searching for files in the Documents/bookImages and the files are there.

```
let paths: NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true)
    if let documentDirectory = paths.firstObject{
        do{
            var path = documentDirectory as! String
            path.appendContentsOf("/bookImages")

            let documents = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path)

            for files in documents {
                let urlForm = NSURL.fileURLWithPath((path) + "/" + files)

                do{
                    try print("\(files): \(urlForm.resourceValuesForKeys([NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey])), with filepath: \(urlForm)")
                    //Prints out folder and files in the desired location

                } catch let error as NSError{
                    print("Can't find key: \(error)")
                }

            }

        }catch let error as NSError{
            print("Can't retrieve contents: \(error)")
        }
    }


9788202350420.jpg: ["NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey": 0], with filepath:    file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DB7BA523-6F75-42CF-92E6- ED2AF171D1AA/Documents/bookImages/9788202350420.jpg
9788203193538.jpg: ["NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey": 0], with filepath: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DB7BA523-6F75-42CF-92E6-ED2AF171D1AA/Documents/bookImages/9788203193538.jpg
9788203254703.jpg: ["NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey": 0], with filepath: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DB7BA523-6F75-42CF-92E6-ED2AF171D1AA/Documents/bookImages/9788203254703.jpg
```

Comment: How do you store the image? Your reading code is good. I'm doing same in my app and all is good. From the top of my head I may assume you're storing your image improperly.

Comment: Right assumption. Luke Patterson got the correct answer. He told me to use UIImagePNGRepresentation and that worked perfect.

Comment: Sorry. Trying to do something similar. Do you use CoreData to save images?

Comment: No. I'm just saving it in a folder in Documents directory. if you want to save to Core Data you'll need to save it as NSData I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize your path variables as global variables at the top of your class, then just modify them within your requestImage method.

Then when you want to retrieve those images, you can just use the same variable name to ensure that it is the exact same path.

EDIT*
I think you may need to be reading some NSData instead. You can use UIImagePNGRepresentation or UIImageJPEGRepresentation to write your file to the documents directory. I found a tutorial [here](http://helpmecodeswift.com/image-manipulation/saving-loading-images)

Comment: That is what kinda goes on here tough... I have the path for Documents directory, then modify it to "/bookImages/" with the file name "123(..).jpg". I do that wherever I want to get images. Global variables will not change anything, a path is a path, isn't it?

Comment: there might be small mistakes in the string of the path. Doing it with global variables ensures the same path. If it still doesn't work then you have a different issue

Comment: I'm gonna test it now

Comment: Will test the UIImagePNGRepresentation tomorrow. Will give you an update then. Thanks

Comment: Using UIImagePNGRepresentation worked perfectly. Thanks, mate!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the issue is happening because you didn't created the `bookImages` folder in the document directory. `NSFileManager` won't create the directories or sub-directories automatically.

```
// Creating directory
do
{
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(documentsPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
}
catch let error as NSError
{
    NSLog("\(error.localizedDescription)")
}

// Saving image
if (data != nil)
{
   // Also it would be better to check the file creation status
   let status = NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(imagePath, contents: data!, attributes: ["NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey" : "YES"])
   if status
   {
      // File created
      self.books[numberInRow].setValue(pathComponent, forKey: "imageurl")
   }
   else
   {
      // File creation failed, update your question on stack overflow, someone will surely help you to find the issue :)
   }
}
```

Comment: The folder is created correctly. I have checked the path. See my updates question.